# How to show error page without changing current URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

I have a custom 500 error page called `500.tsx` and I want to able to show this page when request from client fails with status of 500, but keeping client on old url (for example /auth/register). I have a `axios` listener on error which should do all the work. But could not find a way to do this using `next/router`. Any help appreciated

Comment: I can give you little hint like, 
Make one global boolean flag like `enableErrorPage` make it `true` when you receive error, and just use this flag in all of your existing pages with importing/including your `500.tsx` component. 

And if `enableErrorPage == true` render `500.tsx`

Comment: it sounds like working advice but will not it be considered as bad practice ?

Comment: So for the better way you can also do this logic in your route's JSON, But you just need to work-around and make it centralized.

Comment: did not get actually what you meant here

Answer (score 1):

*Didn't realize OP wanted to show 500 page at first.*

You could look into `router.isFallback` but I am not entirely sure if that's appropriate for this.
It's supposed to be for Page Loading Indicators, but in your case, since the page will never load, it could work.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-true

```
 return router?.isFallback 
   ? <Custom500Page/>
   : <RegularPage/>
```

You can set this variable from `getStaticPaths` method, which runs during build time and is usually used for `[slug]` pages.

```
// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Fetch paths to your slug pages here

  return {
    // paths,
    fallback: true
  }
}
```

Showing 404 page is quite straight forward & This is how we do.

## Rendering 404 page

You can conditionally export a variable called `notFound` as true from `getStaticProps` method.

If the URL is invalid and you don't data to render the page, you simply pass that `notFound` prop as `true` and then the default or custom 404 page will show up automatically preserving your invalid url.

```
// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticProps({ params, preview = false }) {
  let pageData

  try {
    // fetch pageData from API here
  } catch (error) {
    // catch errors
  }

  // check validity or emptyness of data
  // invalid URL (slug) -> empty data from API
  // valid URL (slug) -> valid data from API

  return isObjectEmpty(pageData)
    ? { notFound: true }
    : {
        props: {
          pageData
          // pass other props to the page
        }
      }
}
```

NextJS Docs on `getStaticProps` & `not-found`

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

Comment: what if request fails from client side? i want to show 500 page when axios caught 500 status error

Comment: Pardon me for jumping to conclusions. I re-read the question and adjusted my answer accordingly.